# Modeling a database structure for a students and courses business context

Tags: database-design

I'm developing my first database... (I am using Android and SQL)

I have a list of *students* who each have the *courses* they study.

Regarding the database structure, I have created a table of `students` and other table of `courses` - but I do not know how to keep each *student* for his *list of courses* in the tables.

This means that I have a *student* who studies *courses*: "coursesA", "coursesB", "coursesC".

So I have a table of `subjects` for which I have a `name` and `hours of study`. And I also have a table of `students` - but how do I connect them?

Note: I do not want to save STRING/XML/JSON with a delimiter separation.

Comment: You want a table called student - check the links [here](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) and another table called course. Read a couple of basic database texts,

Comment: To connect them you make a third table for enrollments with foreign keys to both.

Comment: I suggest reading this for basics of database table relationships: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Comment: thanks all - but i still don't get it. how the table look like ? I just starting this .. and i don't have time to deep into all. I will deep into - but now i must know how the table look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Many-To-Many

As suggested in the comments, you need to study to learn the fundamentals of relational database design.

To answer the Question, a student can take many courses and a course can have many students subscribed. That means you have a Many-To-Many relationship.

A Many-To-Many requires a third table, one with at least two columns, the foreign key of the student table and the foreign key of the course table.

Search this site and Stack Overflow, as this has been discussed many many times already.